# How to make Pipewire work with Carla?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, pipewire

I just reinstalled Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 and, in my previous installation, I had replaced pulseaudio with Pipewire as per the instructions on this site: https://trendoceans.com/enable-pipewire-and-disable-pulseaudio-in-ubuntu/. This is to make Carla display all active applications and audio and MIDI devices so that you can connect them in the patchbay. However, in my new installation, I have done the same thing again but Carla still looks like this:

[Carla not showing applications or devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhrM5.png)

What must I do to to get the patchbay working properly?

Answer (score 0):

I added ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream and installed pipewire-audio-client-libraries and restarted and now it works.